# Change default diff utility in Git Extensions commit window

Tags: git, diff, git-extensions

Is there a way to change the arguments to the default diff utility used by git extensions *in the context of the Git Extensions itself, NOT by changing the Git Extensions settings to launch an external utility*?

Answer (score 0):

it's actually rather easy to achieve:

In git extensions, go to

Tools -> Settings -> Git Config

edit the `Difftool command` textbox according to your needs.